# magento: command not found on Magento2 Already Installed through wizard

Tags: magento2, installation, magento-2.0, composer, command-line

Was getting lots of issues installing, so installed Magento2 via Softaculous Installer in CPanel. Installed successfully and site & admin is accessible.

NOW, however, wanting to do things via CLI access, but always get "magento: command not found" when trying to run any of the commands.

Few questions having trouble finding answers for:

1. In order to have access to CLI 'magento' commands, did I *have* to do the initial installation via composer or CLI to start?
2. Is there any way to take the fresh working installation instance I have and enable the CLI magento commands without uninstalling and starting over? (Because was having a difficult time getting a stable, successful installation completed through doing CLI or Composer installation) - **Although** when I did have success a couple of times in the past (before I did something dumb to wack it up beyond my patience for troubleshooting, then deciding to start fresh again...) I DID get access to the Magento commands in CLI, and think they will ultimately prove to be an imperative asset in the future development of this project. :-/

Thanks in advance for any feedback here. Have worked on a couple of projects in Magento 1.*+ in the past, but really want to start this new project off in the new platform.

Comment: Quick questions - is the bin directory in your path? Is the execute bit on bun/magento? What OS? Can you give example command you are running? Yes, the CLI works - no additional setup... Depending on environment (eg is php in path, is it picking up right php.ini etc). I don't know what CPanel is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know if you did actually try to execute it with the php library.

For example my mistake on local OSX:

`bin zarun$ magento 
-bash: magento: command not found`

But it is actually supposed to be:

`bin zarun$ php magento`

Of course take a look at the available commands using the list option:

`bin zarun$ php magento list`

Comment: I saw a PHP tag in that file and thought that I would have to run it from localhost. = )

Answer (score 1):

Prefix your magento syntax with **'php'**

```
 php magento xxxxxx
```

If it has any permission issue then try prefix with **'sudo php'**

```
 sudo php magento xxxxxx
```

Comment: And not to mentioned, it needs to run at var/www/html/magento/bin

Answer (score 0):

the commands should be available even if you did not install it via composer.

the error message you are having mostly is a misleading message covering another error.

you might want to clear the generation and cache folders under var/. (You can safely delete anything here except the .htaccess file).

https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/var

To make sure the classes are regenerated you either must be in developer or default mode (first few lines in your root directories .htaccess file. If it is commented out you should be in default mode) or you have to execute a command to generate all files (which you cant ;) )

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/.htaccess#L5

after this you could try again. maybe just calling bin/magento list, which is a standard command of the symfony console component. It should then give you a list of all magento commands

Answer (score 0):

You might delete the content in var/generation folder.

Answer (score 0):

this did worked for me by adding  php bin

```
php bin/magento list
```